# New Form Value not being submitted

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have two select boxes in a form, one for "Makes" and one for "Models". When you select an option from "Makes", the "Models" dropdown is populated

```
$(function() {
$('#id-make-id').change(function(){
    var iSel = document.getElementById('id-make-id').value;
    $('#div-models').load('populate-models-dropdown.asp?makes='+iSel);
});
});

<select size="1" id="id-make-id" name="frm-make-id">
<option value="1">List of Makes</option
</select>

<div id="div-models">
<select size="1" id="id-model-id" name="frm-model-id">
<option value="1">List of Models</option
</select>
</div>
```

The drop-downs work perfectly. If the form is left unchanged, then the form data submits fine. However, when you submit the form after a change has been made, a new list is in the models drop down, the value of the models dropdown box (frm-model-id) is 0 after submission.

The script inside "populate-models-dropdown.asp" is identical from the form.

Answer (score 0):

The `.load()` method loads the whole page contents into that `<div>` element, you most likely have more things in populate-models-dropdown.asp (e.g. the form itself ), that's probably why it breaks.

To fix this, have such code in populate-models-dropdown.asp:

```vbs
'...generate contents here...
Response.Clear()
Response.Write(rawContents)
Response.End()
```

This will ensure only the raw contents of the drop down HTML will be sent, without other HTML.

If this doesn't work, debug the issue by using Inspect Element on the models drop down (e.g. F12 in Chrome) and see what HTML you got there and why it breaks the form.